# variable scope issue in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got this code:

```
var log = (function () {
 'use strict';
 var fs = require('fs'), baseName='', path = require('path');
 fs.readFile('./config.json', {encoding : 'utf-8'}, function (err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                var parsedConfig = JSON.parse(data);
                logPath = parsedConfig.logFile;
                baseName = path.basename(logPath, '.log');
                if (logPath.length==0 )
                    logPath = './alteredFile.log';
            } else {
                throw err;
            }
        });
}());

var module;
module.exports = log;
```

I'm trying to set variable `baseName` but out side of `fs.readFile` callback it's not set and still empty! how can Iresolve this?

Comment: Also note that IIFEs [aren't typically necessary with Node.js' module scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531329/are-node-js-modules-need-to-be-wrapped-inside-the-module-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`baseName` along with `fs`, and `path` would only be available within the scope of `log` function.  If you want it available outside the scope of `log` (which includes `fs.readFile`) you must declare it within the broader scope that contains `log` (global scope if `log` itself is in global scope).